# Load XML-file with simplexml

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm trying to load an xml file with simplexml. According to `phpinfo()`, the simplexml is enabled. The xml is in the same map as the php-file.

The code below:

```
<?php
if(!$myfilee = simplexml_load_file("test.xml")) {
    echo "dont work";
    print_r($myfilee);
} else {
    echo "works!!";
}
?>
```

It doesn't load. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try this?

```
<?php
if(!simplexml_load_file("test.xml")) {
    echo "dont work";
    print_r($myfilee);
} else {
    echo "works!!";
}
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Your XML file is not valid. Validate your XML file first.

Comment: Your XML file is not valid. Validate your XML file: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input